Sorting a pyspark column after regex and casting to double sorts lexicographically instead of numerically
My data looks like:
+-----------------+
|       columnName|
+-----------------+
|            1 (1)|
|             null|
|          11 (10)|
|            2 (3)|
+-----------------+

The numbers may be either floats or integers, but for simplicity I used integers in the example.
My existing code does two things:

If a column is being sorted, always move the rows with a null value for that column to the end
Sorting by the number in the parentheses

In the example above, I'd expect the sorted order of the numbers with parentheses to be 1, 3, 10, but instead it's sorting to 1, 10, 3. I think that it's sorting lexicographically so the "1" in the "10" is being sorted instead of the entire number "10".
I'm trying to cast to a double, but can't figure out why the case isn't helping. Does anyone know what's wrong here? Thanks in advance.
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def apply_regex(column: Column, pattern: str, group: int):
    extracted = F.regexp_extract(column, pattern, group)
    return F.when(extracted == "", column).otherwise(extracted.cast("double"))

def sort(dataframe, column_name: str, direction: str):
  col = F.col(column_name)
  # Group 3 is the number inside the parentheses
  col = apply_regex(col, r"(\d+(\.\d+)?) \((\d+(\.\d+)?)\)", 3)
  col = F.when(col.isNull(), F.lit(None)).otherwise(col)
  sort_exprs = [col.asc() if direction == "asc" else col.desc()]
  return dataframe.orderBy(*sort_exprs)


You can use a regex to extract the last element in brackets as explained here, and then sort with nulls last (see here). If you don't need the sortColumn after you've used it to order your DataFrame, you can drop the column.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").getOrCreate()

data = [
    Row(columnName="1 (1)"),
    Row(columnName=None),
    Row(columnName="11 (10)"),
    Row(columnName="2 (3)")
]

schema = StructType([
    StructField("columnName", StringType(), True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df.withColumn(
    'sortColumn', F.regexp_extract(F.col("columnName"), r"\(([^()]+)\)$", 1).cast(DoubleType())
).createTempView("df_sortable")

spark.sql("select * from df_sortable order by sortColumn nulls last")

+----------+----------+
|columnName|sortColumn|
+----------+----------+
|     1 (1)|       1.0|
|     2 (3)|       3.0|
|   11 (10)|      10.0|
|      NULL|      NULL|
+----------+----------+

